# Limit Number of Requests for an IP in Strapi

Tags: middleware, strapi, rate-limiting

I have a strapi app in which there is a collection called `Page` and I want to limit the number of requests to `/pages` . I know there is a `rateLimit` middleware but how do i use it and change its default limit interval and max values.

Strapi Version: 4.5.1
Operating System: Windows 11
Database: postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know there is a middleware implemented, as to how to use it. You would [add this middleware to the routes](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/routes.html#middlewares). As an example:

```js
// path: ./src/api/restaurant/routes/restaurant.js

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::restaurant.restaurant', {
  config: {
    find: {
      middlewares: [
        // point to a registered middleware
        'plugin::users-permissions.rateLimit ', 
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This does literally nothing when I add it. :( I don‘t even know how to debug it. Is it actually possible to limit create‘s with this?

Answer (score 1):

For other people wondering how to do this, I found 2 ways:

1. Create a global middleware and use it in routes
2. Create a api middleware and use it in routes

First, you'll need to create a api/global middleware by either using `strapi generate` CLI command or creating files inside: `./src/middlewares/[middleware-name].js/ts` or
`./src/api/[api-name]/middlewares/[middleware-name].js/ts` and there just paste:

```
/**
 * `myLimiter` middleware
 */

import { Strapi } from '@strapi/strapi';
export default (config, { strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    const ratelimit = require('koa2-ratelimit').RateLimit;

    const message = [
      {
        messages: [
          {
            id: 'Auth.form.error.ratelimit',
            message: 'Too many attempts, please try again in a minute.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    return ratelimit.middleware({
      prefixKey: `${ctx.request.path}:${ctx.request.ip}`,
      message,
      ...strapi.config.get('plugin.users-permissions.ratelimit'),
      ...config,
      interval: 1 * 60 * 1000,
      max: 1,
      // WARN: other koa2-ratelimit options (check their github), e.g:
      //   driver: 'memory', // Choose a driver to store the rate limit data (e.g., 'memory', 'redis')
      //   db: strapi.config.environment === 'production' ? strapi.config.database.defaultConnection : ':memory:', // Set the database connection (use in-memory database for development)
      //   duration: 60000, // Time window in milliseconds (e.g., 1 minute)
      //   max: 100, // Maximum number of requests allowed in the time window
      //   whitelist: [], // Array of IP addresses to exclude from rate limiting
      //   blacklist: [], // Array of IP addresses to block immediately

    })(ctx, next);
  };
};
```

After that just go to the `./src/api/[api-name]/routes/[api-name].ts` and use something like:

```
export default factories.createCoreRouter('api::feedback.feedback', {
  prefix: '',
  only: ['create'],
  except: [],
  config: {
    find: {},
    findOne: {},
    create: {
      // middlewares: ['api::[api-name].[middleware-name]'],
      // middlewares: ['global::[middleware-name]'],
      middlewares: ['api::[api-name].my-limiter'], // in my case
    },
    update: {},
    delete: {},
  },
});
```

**NOTE**: no matter how you name your file e.g: myLimiter.ts or my-limiter.ts, strapi always uses Kebab case -> my-limiter is the final middleware name.

#### Resources

- https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/routes
- https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/middlewares#implementation
- https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/middlewares#usage
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa2-ratelimit
- https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/plugins/users-permissions/server/middlewares/rateLimit.js

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I had some problems when I use .ts extension but they are solved by changing the file extension into js